# Customizing output of <jdoc:include type="head"/> in joomla 3.2

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla3.0

So I was reading in the joomla wiki but could not find any further details [than general talk](http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements).

So what I basically want to change is what is being loaded. For the simple main page of my blog joomla loads a a truckload of files, and a a big part is not cached. I want to introduce a caching mechanism and remove the things I am sure I don't need.

So what I in detail want to know is where is:
`<jdoc:include type="head"/>`
implemented?

If a tool exists to realize the caching in a easier fashion than actually writing it myself, i'd be very thankful as well. I am talking about caching pictures, css and javascript files by setting expire to in one year. Afterwards invalidating the cached files by adding a version number to the request string.

[image]

Comment: i think there an option in joomla global configuration to enable caching and compression

Comment: I'll let others speak to the general issue of if there is a plugin to compress/combine files. However, my understanding is that 304 Not modified means that your browser is using the cached version. It still made a request for the file (so there is that overhead), but it didn't download the whole file again, just the response code.

Comment: @DavidFritsch correct. But yeah, we basically ask the server if the file is still the same, then work with that. There is 15 requests for this - only on the part of what we can see on the screenshot. This is not good.

Comment: I assume that you have multiple 3rd party extensions installed on your Joomla site as a fresh install of Joomla 3.2 with the default Protostar template doesn't load all those assets. Having tested it myself, I only see 14. Maybe if you compiled a screenshot showing all the assets being loaded, it might be easier to provide a more accurate answer

Comment: thanks @Lodder you seem to be around a lot, that's great. Well it turned out the other statements came from a chrome extension \*blush\* and are all read from the cache. I didn't expect it to show up in my developer debug window. So joomla is basically loading what you see in the screenshot, minus the logo pictures at the bottom (i load them)

Answer (score 2):

I am citing RedEye from the joomla forums:

"The file is in /libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php
But don't change this file, make an override. Copy it somewhere (your template folder for example) and include the file in your template index.php"

I'll have a go at this as soon as I finished what I started in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

I find the [JCH Optimize plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/12088) works really well in combining, minimizing, and caching JavaScript and CSS files.  There's a free and paid version of it.  You can have it just cache the main Joomla core and template files, or you can have it do some or all of the extensions that you have in your install too.  You can exclude certain files if you run into a problem. You may have to play with the plugin order and put this one towards the bottom of the list so that it loads later and grabs most of the files to optimize.

For images: If you're using an Apache web server, you can add ExpiresByType rules in the .htaccess file or httpd.conf or a conf.d file. I wouldn't include the css and js files here because I would let JCH Optimize handle them. Most of my sites have changing content so I don't typically set that very far in the future. Here's some sample code you could use.

```
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
   # Enable expirations
   ExpiresActive On

   # Default directive - covers html, etc
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 minutes"

   # My favicon
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

   # Images
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

   </IfModule>
```

For more reading, see the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) on it.

Finally, jQuery can be sourced from Google using another handy free extension called jQuery Easy. You can even set it to load jQuery securely (https). Sorry, I don't have enough points to post a link.